# Best place to call a method to adjust layout in iOS

Tags: layout, ios7, orientation, landscape, portrait

I am having a problem modifying my layout when switching from portrait to landscape. The layouts are as shown below. As you can see, the switch requires repositioning the two inner panels (light grey) relative to one another. The view controller is embedded in a navigation controller and the panels contain buttons which fire segues to further view controllers.

[image: portrait orientation]

[image: landscape orientation]

All the resizing is nicely taken care of by AutoLayout, but the repositioning requires using CGRect. On screen rotation is dealt with by

```
- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        self.topImagePanel.frame = CGRectMake(44, 16, 196, 392);
        self.bottomImagePanel.frame = CGRectMake(44, 407, 196, 392);
    } else {
        self.topImagePanel.frame = CGRectMake(72, 64, 196, 392);
        self.bottomImagePanel.frame = CGRectMake(268, 64, 196, 392);
    }
}
```

And the following method deals with startup and navigating back to the home screen.

```
- (void) adjustLayoutToOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation)){
        self.topImagePanel.frame = CGRectMake(72, 64, 196, 392);
        self.bottomImagePanel.frame = CGRectMake(268, 64, 196, 392);
    } else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation)) {
        self.topImagePanel.frame = CGRectMake(44, 16, 196, 392);
        self.bottomImagePanel.frame = CGRectMake(44, 407, 196, 392);
    }
}
```

The most effective place to call this method from seems to be viewDidAppear. The problem is that whenever the view appears in landscape mode. It appears first as laid out in the storyboard (i.e. in portrait mode) for a brief interval before being replaced by the correct layout.

I have tried calling from viewWillAppear but although the method is called, the landscape layout simply never appears.I have also tried calling from viewDidLayoutSubviews. The landscape layout appears (when navigating back although not on start up) but with the same glitch as described above. One more thing I have tried is using different view controllers for the different layouts but it really seems to be overkill and causes more problems than it solves. Help appreciated.